# Загрузка небольших картинок для админки

Tags: asp.net-core

Есть небольшой проект ASP.NET Core(API) + React. Нужно реализовать изменение картинок через админку. Их совсем мало(2) и в ближайшее время вряд ли будет больше, 500 Кб+- размер одного файла. Вопрос в том, стоит ли для такого мелкого проекта хранить картинки в БД или как лучше ? И если хранить в файловой системе, то по какому пути надо сохранять файлы, т.е я имею в виду какой-то специальный Path каталога, внутри которого проект, или же мне получать каждый раз временный путь(вроде б есть метод получения названия для временного файла) ? Но мне это не очень нравится = картинок будет мало и имена будут фиксированные(т.е хочется менять одни и те же файлы-картинки). Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, я просто реально не понимаю.